# Error when starting a new activity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am trying to start a new activity that opens a calendar when the user clicks on the first option (case 0). But I get the error that

> The constructor Intent(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, Class) is undefined

I'm not sure why I am getting this or even if I should be using Intent to call CalendarViewSampleActivity.  The code that I tried using is below under case 0.

```
private void openReserveDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.new_reserv_title)
            .setItems(R.array.reservations,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                            switch(i){
                            case 0:
                                Intent in = new Intent(this, CalendarViewSampleActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                //take out
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                // change reservation
                                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.container, new LocationFragment()).commit();
                                //take out
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                // cancel reservation
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`, `this` refers to the listener, not to your activity. Use `getApplicationContext()` instated in the Intent constructor should do the trick.

Comment: so do I do: Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalendarViewSampleActivity.class); and leave the rest the same?

Comment: Yes. You can also create your intent as `final Intent in = new Intent(this, CalendarViewSampleActivity.class);` if you're outside the OnClickListener block